# Specifying a convergence criterion for the approximate randomization test

Tags: statistical-significance, permutation-test

All documents (e.g., (1,2)) that I have read on approximate randomization test indicate that one needs to choose the number of shuffles prior to running the approximate randomization test. Example from (1), where the number of shuffles is fixed to 9,999:

[image]

I wonder whether it would be OK to specify a convergence criterion on the significance level, instead of pre-defining a number of shuffles. (and if so, what would be a reasonable convergence criterion and how comes few people if any uses one.)

E.g., one such convergence criterion could be

> stop the approximate randomization test if the significance level hasn't varied more than $\pm0.01$ over the last 50 shuffles.

---

The main rationale would be that the convergence speed of the significance level depends on the dataset and the analyzed system.

Below are some examples of number of shuffles (x-axis) vs. significance level (y-axis), as we can see the significance level sometimes converges before 9,999:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Conversely, one could (?) imagine cases where the significance level hasn't converged yet after 9,999 shuffles.

---

1. Chinchor, Nancy. "The statistical significance of the MUC-4 results." In Proceedings of the 4th conference on Message understanding, pp. 30-50. Association for Computational Linguistics, 1992. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=9100345284812509896&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5
2. Morgan, William. "Statistical hypothesis tests for NLP." https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14737537630072698879&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5

Comment: Frank, we don't need an [approximate-randomization] tag for this (that you seem to have created). It's standard permutation test, our tag for this is [permutation-test].

Comment: @amoeba thanks, I think approximate randomization test = approximate permutation test, so I guess we can indeed merge it with permutation-test. Shall I go ahead and retag?

Comment: I'd say yes. In fact I don't see anything "approximate" about this procedure, apart from using only a subset of all possible permutations, but that's done almost always, so I guess most questions in [permutation-test] tag are about "approximate" permutation test (I've never seen this terminology before though).

Comment: I retagged your two Qs.

Comment: @amoeba Thank you, sorry I got buried with some paper deadlines.